# Postgres find sequence with same intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
=> \d test_table;
               Table "public.test_table"
   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 timestamp   | bigint  |           |          |
 source      | inet    |           |          |
 destination | inet    |           |          |
 type        | integer |           |          |
```

Let's say there's a table with the same above, that contains the network connection information, with a lot more ip pairs, and types than shown below.

```
rawdb=> select * from test_table order by timestamp;
 timestamp  |   source    | destination | type
------------+-------------+-------------+------
 1586940900 | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.2 |    1
 1586940960 | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.2 |    1
 1586941020 | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.2 |    1
 1586941080 | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.2 |    1
 1586941140 | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.2 |    1
(5 rows)
```

Out of the table, I need to find the connection pair that are always connecting every `x` interval. For example, in the rows above, the connection between the ip pair `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.2` is happening every 60s intervals.

The table above would be the answer to the question "how many ip pairs are connecting every 60s over the last 5 min?"

**Question**

How do I extract those periodic connections for various intervals with the same type, same ip pair? Connections that are 1 min peridoically, 5 min perodically, 30 min perodically.

The baseline is I can provide the `x` to search for (e.g. every 60s, every 5 min, every 1 hour, etc), the best case solution is to be able to find `x` without being provided. 
The result format I need is the same as the table above.

Is it possible to do all of this in SQL? I have done some research on doing gap analysis on the postgres tables, but this is not to find out the gaps, but rather the continuous sequence.

Comment: Unrelated, but: a column named "timestamp" which in fact is a `bigint` sure sounds confusing. Why isn't the "timestamp" declared as a `timestamp`? https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: I didn't realize there's `timestamp` datatype. Thanks for the info, I'll convert it to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly the output is, you are after. But the difference between two connections of the same source/destination combination can be calculated using a window function.

Something like:

```
select distinct source, destination
from (
  select *,
         lead("timestamp") over w - "timestamp" as diff
  from test_table
  window w as (partition by source, destination order by "timestamp")
) t
where diff = 60
```

`lead("timestamp") over w - "timestamp"` calculates the difference between the current row's timestamp and the next one for the same source/destination pair. I moved the window definition into the FROM clause to make the expression that calculates the diff more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's almost what I want exactly. I can tweak it a bit more to check for the count of the sequence, since the timestamp is aggregated to 1min, I can check for count of the sequence to 5min, to look for flows with 1 min periodic intervals for 5 consecutive intervals.